# Select doesn't work on IQueryable but does on IList

Tags: c#, .net, linq, subsonic, subsonic-simplerepository

I have two lines of code, one is

```
AllItems().Where(c => c.Id== id)
          .Select(d => new Quality(d.QualityType)).ToList();
```

and the other one

```
AllItems().Where(c => c.Id== id).ToList()
          .Select(d => new Quality(d.QualityType)).ToList();
```

The only difference is on the second statement `ToList()` is called after the `Where` statement. The second statment works just fine.

On the first statement, the default parameterless constructor is hit instead of the constructor with the parameter. so the list is created but the objects in the list are initialized with default values rather than with the d.QualityType.

you can see the full source of the file in question at (Method: GetBestQualityInHistory)

https://github.com/kayone/NzbDrone/blob/master/NzbDrone.Core/Providers/HistoryProvider.cs

**Edit: After further investigation, this seems to be a SubSonic bug, if the Last `ToList` is replaced by an `OrderBy` subsonic throws an `The construtor 'Void .ctor(NzbDrone.Core.Repository.Quality.QualityTypes, Boolean)' is not supported`.

Comment: You're calling `ToList` in *both* cases here... but in the second case you're calling it *twice*. Why?

Comment: sorry, that was just wrong copy past

Comment: What type is AllItems? Is it just an in memory list or is it something supplied to you by for example a persistence framework?

could be relevant as the persistance framework will be handling the call if no ToList is used. As far as I know .net handles it after tolist (since it is a list<T> afterwards)

Comment: it's an IQueryable<History>, but its proxied by SubSonic Simple Repository using castle.

Comment: @Keivan: And what are you doing with the result afterwards? It sounds like this could easily be a SubSonic bug... it's *always* worth making your LINQ provider clear in a question.

Comment: @Keivan: I've just had a look at the full code, and noticed you're calling `OrderBy` and ignoring the results... probably unrelated, but definitely a bug, unless SubSonic is doing *really* weird stuff. LINQ query operators aren't meant to change the source you call them on - they're meant to return a new query with the appropriate modifications (e.g. added ordering).

Comment: basically a ToList() is called after, I'll update the question.

Comment: @jon, yeah, just noticed that, before Sort was called on the list. which modifies the list itself, when I updated the code I missed that now I'm using Linq's order and should just chain it. thanks for the tip.

Comment: I've just tested this with a normal list but this works as expected (calling the specified constructor) so to me this is SubSonic related rather than linq.

Comment: Yes, just played around with it a little bit, and in some cases subsonic throws and NotSupported exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If SubSonic works in the same way as Entity framework you cannot use constructors with parameters - you must use parameterless constructors and initializers. My very high level explanation of this is that the query is not executed as is - it is translated to SQL and because of that you must use property initializers so that expression tree knows which properties in the projected type should be filled by values. When using constructor with parameters, expression tree doesn't know where the passed parameter belongs to (it doesn't check content of the constructor). The real constructor (parameterless) is called once you execute `Tolist` and result set is materialized into `QuantityType` instances.

Comment: the code was using initializers originally, I changed it to constructor to track down the issue.

Comment: Holy wrap. I just tested the use of parameterized constructors in EF 3.5 and I expected you to be wrong... However, you are right. I'm dazzled. EF throws an "Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities." exception. Is this still the case in EF 4.0? I do this all the time with LINQ to SQL.

Comment: @Steven: Yes it is same in EFv4 an according to this it should be the same in Linq-to-sql as well but I didn't try it myself.

Comment: Here is the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx#linqtosql_topic13 for Linq-to-sql. I forgot to place it in former comment.

Comment: Calling a parameterized constructor within a select method has worked with LINQ to SQL from day one; I use it all the time. The only catch is, that L2S prevents you from creating L2S entities yourself inside a `Select`.

Answer (score 0):

*This isn't really an answer, and I was going to make it a comment, but needed more room for code snippet.*

Judging by the SubSonic code, I'm pretty sure that in some cases where you get the "constructor not supported" errors, SS is for some reason trying to parse your `new ...()` statement into SQL. The offending method is part of the SQL Formatter, and looks like it only handles DateTime:

```
    protected override NewExpression VisitNew(NewExpression nex)
    {
        if (nex.Constructor.DeclaringType == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            // ...omitted for brevity...
        }
        throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("The construtor '{0}' is not supported", nex.Constructor));
    }
```

I think that would normally be hit if you did something like:

someData
        .Where(data => data.CreatedDate <= new DateTime(2011, 12, 01))
        .Select(data => data)

Then that `newDateTime` would be translated to SQL.
So however you change the Linq to get that exception, I think that is what is happening.
I assume this is because if you add an `.OrderBy()` *after* the `.Select()` then you are no longer calling the OrderBy on the IQueryable of whatever AllItems() returns, but instead trying to order by what is returned by the .Select(), which is the enumerable of new Quality obejcts, so SS probably tries to turn all that into SQL.

I'm wondering if it would work right if you reversed it?

```
AllItems().Where(c => c.Id== id)
      .OrderBy(d => d.QualityType)
      .Select(d => new Quality(d.QualityType));
```